# Get URL from shortcode tag

Tags: php, shortcode, the-content, regex

I am running a wordpress site and I need the correct regex syntax to get a URL from some shortcode that is returned inside the_content().

When I use the_content(), it will return something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nulla enim, euismod ut pharetra nec, commodo a augue. Etiam sit amet nibh mauris, eu ornare purus. Vestibulum sed sem enim, sit amet congue leo. 

[video mp4=<<insert video url here>> poster=<<insert imgae placeholder url>>]
```

How can I get just the video mp4 URL?

Comment: This isn't a WordPress question, IMHO. If reworded, it could be though.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use regex for this. WordPress has a [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to do this work for you.

That codex page includes one of my favorite codex code snippets:

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

    ...
```

Right at the start of the function registering the shortcode it does the following:

- take the user-submitted shortcodes and fill them in with defaults if they aren't provided
- takes the `$atts` argument and turn each valued into a variable (e.g. `$foo`, `$bar`, etc.)

  - For you, you'd get `$mp4` and `$poster`

Answer (score 1):

Catch the `mp4` url with this:

```
<?php
    $text = get_the_content(); //untested with get_the_content()
    preg_match_all("\bmp4="(.+)\b", $text, $matches);
    var_dump($matches[0]);
?>
```

Eg. *[video mp4="http://somevideo.com/abc"]*, would output:

```
http://somevideo.com/abc
```

This is my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jany-M/4be37803d1dedd1113390dfcdad97c14), the example in it works for me, but results might differ depending on `$text`.

Comment: your preg_match_all is giving a syntax error but looks like a nice idea.

Comment: This is my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jany-M/4be37803d1dedd1113390dfcdad97c14), the example in it works for me, but results might differ depending on `$text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring and strpos to extract this

```
$spos = strpos($getContent,"mp4=");
if($spos) {
$spos = $spos+4;//4 for four charactars mp4= 
$epos = strpos($getContent,' ',$spos) - $spos;
$url = substr($getContent,$spos,$epos);
echo $url;
}
```